# Android - Why do I need to invalidate this view manually?

Tags: android, animation, view, runnable, invalidation

I have the following method inside my MainActivity:

```
public void animationLogoFromCenterToTop(){

        final TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, CENTER_SCREEN_LOGO,
                                                                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f);

        translate.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        translate.setFillAfter(true);
        translate.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator() );
        translate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                imageViewMainLogo.invalidate();//Workaround that works
                UtilLog.d(TAG, "onAnimationStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                UtilLog.d(TAG, "onAnimationRepeat");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                UtilLog.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd");
            }
        });

        imageViewMainLogo.startAnimation(translate);

        topBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

I call that method inside the following fragment:

```
public class SplashFragment extends TrackedFragment{

    private static final String TAG = SplashFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIMER_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000;

    private Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override//This runs in the UI Thread!
        public void run() {

            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).animationLogoFromCenterToTop();

            if( UtilStorage.getCurrentLoggedInUser() != null ){

                UtilFragments.replaceFragmentStackingNewOneWithoutAddingToStack(getActivity(), 
                                                                                new StatusFragment(),
                                                                                R.id.fragment_container,
                                                                                R.anim.fadein_long, 0, 0, 0);   
            }else{
                UtilFragments.replaceFragmentStackingNewOneWithoutAddingToStack(getActivity(), 
                                                                                new MainFragment(), 
                                                                                R.id.fragment_container,
                                                                                R.anim.fadein_long, 0, 0, 0);   
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         final View wholeFragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash, container, false);

         return wholeFragmentLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){

        super.onResume();

        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, SPLASH_SCREEN_TIMER_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    }
}
```

If I remove the ***imageViewMainLogo.invalidate();*** line inside the *animationLogoFromCenterToTop()* method that ImageView sometimes disappears completely! If I go to the Developer Options menu on the phone and select the "Show layout bounds" option I can confirm that the view is not even there because the place where it is supposed to be does not even have its layout bounders drew.

This behaviour seems to be random. Sometimes the ImageView appears and sometime it does not and, once the ImageView disappears, it never goes back no matter what I do (even if I kill the app and start it again, the ImageView just never show up again (even though the animation is called as I can confirm with the line *UtilLog.d(TAG, "onAnimationStart");*

If I leave that invalidate() workaround there then it always works. However, I do not understand why that is. Can someone please explain me why should I manually call imageViewMainLogo.invalidate() there ???

This bug happens on both high-end (Nexus 4, Galaxy S 3) and low-end (LG Vodaphone) devices I have here although it seems in low-end devices the image disappears much quicker.

Comment: Does it more likely to disappear after 1 second?\

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you have to call your method inside  `onWindowFocusChanged()` instead of `onResume`.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin No, when it disappears it happens straight away. It does not show the ImageView for a fraction of a time or anything similar. When the Activity (and consequently the Fragment) starts the ImageView is simply not there. Just to clarify, what I mean by "disappears much quicker" in my question is that it will likely happen  (on a low end device) as soon as I leave the Activity/Fragment (with the back button) and open the app again. For higher end devices, I have to leave and re-open the app about 3 or 4 times before the ImageView disappears.